# CRUD operations in django rest framework having many-to-many fields relationship

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I am using django rest framework for creating REST APIs. My model contains one many-to-many field and I am facing some complications in serializing it.

models.py

```
class CustomerMaster(models.Model):
    customer_key = models.IntegerField(db_column='CUSTOMER_KEY', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    first_name = models.TextField(db_column='FIRST_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    last_name = models.TextField(db_column='LAST_NAME', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    email = models.CharField(db_column='EMAIL', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    gender = models.TextField(db_column='GENDER', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    dob = models.DateField(db_column='DOB', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    phone = models.CharField(db_column='PHONE', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    address = models.TextField(db_column='ADDRESS', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
  ...

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'customer_master'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + self.last_name

class Segment(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    folder = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    selection = JSONField()
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    updatedAt = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    createdBy = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    contact = models.ManyToManyField(CustomerMaster)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('pk', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name',)

class CustomerEmailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomerMaster
        fields = ('email', )

class SegmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = CustomerEmailSerializer(many=True)
    createdBy = UserSerializer(required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ('name', 'folder', 'selection', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy', 'contact')
```

My GET Request Output:

```
    {
        "name": "asgg",
        "folder": "Ticketing",
        "selection": "{\"qq\": \"ee\"}",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "contact": [
            {
                "email": "aakashnihalani26@gmail.com"
            },
            {
                "email": "qwerty@gmail.com"
            }
        ]
    }
```

I want my output something like this:

```
    {
        "name": "asgg",
        "folder": "Ticketing",
        "selection": "{\"qq\": \"ee\"}",
        "createdAt": null,
        "updatedAt": null,
        "createdBy": null,
        "contact": [
            "aakashnihalani26@gmail.com",
            "qwerty@gmail.com"
        ]
    }
```

I am using python 3.7, django 2.2.11, django rest framework 3.11.0

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What problems you are facing ?

Comment: I want my api output as mentioned as compared to my current output.(Both are mentioned in the description)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested serializer. You can use the [`SlugRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield).

```
class SegmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contact = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field='email')
    createdBy = UserSerializer(required=False)


    class Meta:
        model = Segment
        fields = ('name', 'folder', 'selection', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', 'createdBy', 'contact')
```

Comment: Thanks! it works. But I need to make POST requests as well, so I removed `read_only=True` and added a `queryset` to `SlugRelatedField` to make it work.